# Reaction of ether with HCl

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ethers

Most of the reactions undergo ring expansion whenever favourable.
But this reaction [1, p. 514] doesn't seems to do so:

> **Practice Problem 11.18** Provide a mechanism for the following reaction.
>
> [image: Reaction between (1‐methoxyethyl)cyclopentane and HCl]

Could anybody explain why?

#### References

1. Solomons, T. W. G.; Fryhle, C. B.; Snyder, S. A. Organic Chemistry, 12e ed.; *John Wiley & Sons, Inc: Hoboken, NJ*, **2016**. ISBN 978-1-118-87576-6.

Comment: Presence of a good nucleophile Cl- that captures the stable cation faster than any ring expansion. Also 5 ring is pretty stable so expansion to 6 is not particularly favoured.

Comment: But it does rearrange to a tertiary cation.....wouldn't it be better if it's a tertiary cation in a 6 membered ring?

Comment: No, 6 ring is not better than 5

Comment: Oh, I had thought otherwise. What's the reason for it?

Comment: Ring strain slightly lower with 5 than 6

Comment: In the future, please add complete reference to the textbook you are quoting from (page number(s), edition, publisher etc.: see my edit as an example). Also, this question somewhat looks like a "covert" homework question: probably you can share with us some of your own thoughts. Other than that, it's a nice question IMO.

Comment: Yea will see to it that happens from the next time.

Comment: How would you get a tertiary cation if ring expansion occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things to consider: What would be the energy difference between before and after rearrangement from initial $2^\circ$-carbocation (**I**) and each of rearranged carbocations **II** and **III**:

[image: Cyclopentane Rearrangement]

It is obvious that the rearrangement of carbocation **I** to give carbocation **II** by ring expansion have minimal energy change since both initial and final carbocations are $2^\circ$ and ring expansion does not relieve too much energy because it is cyclopentyl to cyclohexyl. However, the rearrangement of carbocation **I** to give carbocation **III** by 1,2-hydride transfer relieves good amount of energy since initial carbocation is $2^\circ$ and final rearranged carbocation is $3^\circ$. Although the carbocation **II** would undergo further stabilization by 1,2-hydride transfer to relieve extra energy, **I** to **III** happens much faster than **I** to **II** transfer to give **3** as the major product.